# Wide column-spanning minted listing with caption (twocolumn)

Tags: floats, minted

In a twocolumn document class, can I use minted to display a code excerpt which spans both columns?

A figure, containing a minted listing, can instead be used to cross both columns. Figures allow the specification of useful attributes such as `\caption` and `\label`. When I use minted for code excerpts, its `listings` environment can allow a `\caption` and `\label` to be specified. The advantage of using the `listings` environment includes that `\listoflistings` will insert a list of all listings. (If I use a figure instead, the listing will not be included in the list of listings.)

Is there a way to use minted to specify a wide listing in a twocolumn document with a caption and label?